# Reinstalling node.js in windows from scratch to a NEW/DIFFERENT folder

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-installer, reinstall

I need to reinstall nodejs in windows 7 in a shorter character folder (closer to root, that is) than the one previously used since the character length is giving me problems with some packages.

However, when I reinstall, npm always installs in the PREVIOUS folder. How can I perform a new, fresh installation? Specifically, where I can select the folder where the packages will be installed?

[image: Notice second path.]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out about:

[npm config set prefix C:\blahblahblah](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2207)

Hope this solves my problem.